# Document of Functions that accept iterators

Tags: python, function, iterator

I was having trouble with a project and was later able to successfully complete it. However, while running through some code written by someone else, I noticed they were able to utilize an iterator (`for` loop)  within the join-function.

example:

```
' '.join(x for x in name.split('*'))
```

I thought this was awesome as it helped me cut down lines of code from my original draft.

So my question is: Are there any documents that have a list of functions that accept iterators?

Comment: If you know a function takes a list, assume it takes an arbitrary iterable until proven otherwise. An obvious class of exceptions would be functions that you know modify the list in-place.

Comment: noted. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be mistaken here, but I think what you mean by iterator is in fact called a list comprehension in python. It's not that the list comprehension in question does not return an iterable, but it seems that you are impressed not with the fact that you could pass an iterable to the join function, but instead that the fact that you could put what seems to be flow control inline. Again, tell me if I'm wrong about this.

List comprehensions can be in the form of tuples (returns a generator) or lists (returns a list). To see the difference between these two, type the following in a python shell:

```
>>> (x for x in 'cool')
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03980990>

>>> [x for x in 'cool']
['c', 'o', 'o', 'l']
```

I would imagine it is obvious how you can work with a list, but if you want to learn more about how generators work, you might want to [check this out](https://realpython.com/blog/python/introduction-to-python-generators/).

Also, the fun doesn't end there with list comprehensions. The possibilities are endless.

```
>>> [x for x in [1,5,4,7,8,2,6,3] if x > 3]
[5, 4, 7, 8, 6]

>>> [(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

To learn more about list comprehensions in general, [try here](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html).

Comment: You're correct thats exactly the reason why i was impressed.Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

They're called *generators*, and they work in many places that accept `list`s or `tuple`s. The generic term for all three is *iterable*. But it depends on what the code in question does. If it just iterates then a generator will work. If it tries to get the `len()` or access items by index, it won't.

There isn't a list of functions that accept generators or iterables, no; nobody organizes documentation that way.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the argument to `str.join()` in your example is called a "generator expression". A generator expression evals to an iterable object 
 - note that an iterable is not necessarily an iterator (but iterators are iterable).

I assume your question really was about "functions that accept generator expressions". If yes, the answer is above: any function that expects an iterable, since arguments are eval'd before being passed so the generator expression is turned into an iterable before the function is actually called.

Note that there's a distinction to be made between iterables and "sequences types" (strings, tuples, lists, sets etc): the later are indeed iterable, *but* they have some other specifities too (ie they usually have a length, can be iterated more than once etc) so not all functions expecting a sequence will work with non-sequence iterators. But this is usually documented.